# spring integration poller with overnight cron expression

Tags: spring-integration, cronexpression

We have requirement to poll for file overnight eg 8pm tonight to next day morning 10AM. How this can be achieved using cron expression in spring integration poller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will poll at the top of each hour in the range you require...

```
"0 0 0-10,20-23 * * *"
```